# BigQuery How to fill column looking the previous values of the same?

Tags: google-bigquery

Good morning, guys. How are you?

I need your help to understanding how to solve this problem, please.

I need fill column, that is being created, looking to previous values of the same column. Like this:

[image]

Any help will apreciate. Thank you!

Comment: You can use ```lag``` to check previous value. For detailed answer please share sample data set and expected output.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I will add the expected output.

But, lag function needed reference to column and is this my problem. How reference the current column?